# Python Discord.py TextChannel creation overwrites error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

[image]

> the code that is causing the error is:

```
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
    client.get_user(MessageManager["TextChannels"][z]["personID"]): 
    discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
}
guild_category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, id=orders_category_ID)
    
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name = idorder, category=guild_category ,overwrites=overwrites)
```

> Everything was working good and i had to restart the bot and now its showing this error. Could this be a problem with discord.py version?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution:

```
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name = idorder, category=guild_category)# ,overwrites=overwrites)
    ### guild.default_role ###
    overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
    overwrite.read_messages = False
    await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
    
    ### admin_role ###
    overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
    overwrite.read_messages = True
    await channel.set_permissions(admin_role, overwrite=overwrite)
    
    ### the worker ###
    overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
    overwrite.read_messages = True
    await channel.set_permissions(client.get_user(MessageManager["TextChannels"][z]["personID"]), overwrite=overwrite)
```

We need to do this instead of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

> So, i found the solution:

The solution is correct, but incomplete. In the original version, which causes an error, the channel is created immediately with the assigned rights, which slightly speeds up the program execution. The second option is not so fast, since all operations for editing the channel take some time. We are waiting for more answers, since the error appeared only from today, and it is not known what caused it.